# Select only first level of descendants with jQuery - is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a jQuery plugin to lock rows or columns in a table a la Excel's freeze panes. (There are a number of other fine solutions for this, but none of them have worked for me for various reasons. I think it might have something to do with the table being inside a modal popup. But I digress.)

As part of this I'm trying to select the first *n* rows or columns of a particular table, specified in the plugin options. The trouble is that some of the rows contain other nested tables. I unfortunately can't do anything about this. So my question is, how do I get only the first level of `<tr>`s within a table? Using `.children('tr')` isn't always working because the row isn't necessarily the direct child of the table--there might be a `<thead>` <strike>or (ideally) the user might be able to call the plugin on a containing element and it should be smart enough to find the table(s) inside it</strike>.
**Edit:** Actually, now I'm thinking that second bit is not going to work if we have to select the table by id. But I don't think it's too much to ask that people use the plugin only on a table, since that's kind of what it's for...

In short: how do I select only the first level of table rows that may or may not be the direct child of a particular containing element?

What I came up with so far, based on the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977883/selecting-only-first-level-elements-in-jquery#977891), was this:

```
$el.find('tr:not(tr tr):lt('+base.options.rows+')')
```

and for the columns:

```
$el.find('tr:not(tr tr)').find('(td,th):lt('+base.options.columns+')')
```

But that seems horribly long and clunky and I'm wondering if there's a shorter/cleaner way of doing it. Or is there a way just using plain old javascript?

**Edit 2:** [Apparently the selector version is actually faster than .not()](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not). News to me.

Comment: I think what I'm gathering from this is that I need to have an id on the outer table. Thanks guys! Wish I could accept more than one answer.

Comment: Oops. This is almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031638/get-most-upper-descendant-descendants-in-jquery Figures, I search for a week and then find the same question 3 hours after posting mine. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your table an "ID" so you have a starting point and use the direct child selector

```
$('tableID, tableID > tbody,tableID > thead, tableID > tfoot').children('tr')
```

As tr can be under the table, tbody, or thead for that specific table

Answer (score 3):

Use the correct selector. In this case, that would be `>`, the direct child selector:

```
$el.find('#table > tbody tr > td, #table > tbody tr > th');
```

See "[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)" for other options.

Alternatively, just iterate over all direct children of `tbody`:

```
var cells = $el.children('tbody').children('tr').children();
```

Since only `td` and `tr` are allowed as children of `tr`, that should already be the list that you want.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how that would solve my issue... the nested `<td>`s are still direct children of `<tr>`s so wouldn't that select them as well? (Sorry, I'm still a bit fuzzy on CSS3 selectors.)

Comment: Sorry, you need to start with the table.